# prove uniqueness of a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is a measure space and $\mathcal{\overline{M}}:=\{E\cup F:E\in\mathcal{M}\text{ and }F\subset N\text{ for some }N\in \mathcal{N}\}$ is a completion of $\mathcal{M}$ with respect to $\mu$ where $\mathcal{N}:=\{N\in\mathcal{M}:\mu(N)=0\},$ then $\mathcal{\overline{M}}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

If now $\overline{\mu}(E\cup F):=\mu(E)$ then $\overline{\mu}$ is a complete measure.

Need to prove the uniqueness of the measure, but I am not following the proof 100%.

Suppose $\mu^{\prime}$ is another measure on $\mathcal{\overline{M}}$ that extends $\mu$ to a complete measure. So I guess we need to show that $\mu^{\prime}=\overline{\mu}$

let $E\cup F\in\overline{\mathcal{M}}$ with $E\in\mathcal{M}$ and $F\subset N\in\mathcal{N}$ we have

$\mu^{\prime}(E)\le \mu^{\prime}(E\cup F)\le \mu^{\prime}(E\cup N)=\mu(E\cup N)\le \mu(E)+\mu(N)=\mu(E)=\mu^{\prime}(E)$ (since $E\in\mathcal{M}$)

so $\mu^{\prime}(E\cup F)=\mu(E)=\overline{\mu}(E\cup F)$ hence $\mu^{\prime}=\mu$

It is the line with the inequalities that I dont' get.

1)$\mu^{\prime}(E)\le \mu^{\prime}(E\cup F)$ this I think follows from $E\subset E\cup F$

2)$\mu^{\prime}(E\cup F)\le \mu^{\prime}(E\cup N)$ as $E\cup F\subset E\cup N$

3) $\mu^{\prime}(E\cup N)=\mu(E\cup N)$ where does this one come from?

4) $\mu(E\cup N)\le \mu(E)+\mu(N)$ subaddtivity of the measure

5)$\mu(E)=\mu^{\prime}(E)$ since $N$ is a null-set but then the equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) and (2) exactly, this follows from monotonicity of $\mu'$, for (3) note, that $\mu'$ extends $\mu$, and both $E, N \in \mathcal M$, so from $\mu'|_{\mathcal M} = \mu$ and $E \cup N \in \mathcal M$ we have 
$$ \mu'(E \cup N) = \mu(E \cup N). $$

Comment: can the same argument like in (3) be used for $\mu^{\prime}(E)=\mu(E)$?

Comment: @HeidiE Yes, exactly.